# Redux/Reducer correct way to spread previous unchanged nested state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

In redux or reducer pattern, for nested objects do you need to deeply spread every level of the previous state or is that only necessary on the object that you are updating?
For example if you have some state that looks like this:

```
   {
      name: { 
        first: 'Bob',
        last: 'Smith'
      },
      address: {
        streetName: '123 fake st',
        city: "New York"
      }

   };
```

And then a reducer that updates the address:

```
case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    address: {
      ...state.address,
      city: 'Baltimore'
    }
  };
```

I am just confused wether this is right or not in terms of immutability. Since the ...state will only return the reference to the old name object and not an entire new object. Would I also need to spread ...state.name even though it is not being changed? I know there are a lot of questions about nested state and reducers and they all say that you need to return a new copy but they all show just ...state for the previous state and I haven't been able to find one that describes this and why you don't need to spread all the old nested state if that's the case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. In short, in redux the return value from reducer will become the next value for the store. Only requirement is that we cannot change the state directly (unless you use something like Immutable.js)

What `...state` does is it spread the object out. So your return value will become something like this

```js
{
      name: { 
        first: 'Bob',
        last: 'Smith'
      },
      address: {
        streetName: '123 fake st',
        city: "New York"
      },
      address: {
        streetName: '123 fake st',
        city: "New York",
        city: 'Baltimore'
      }

}
```

For object that has duplicate key, Javascript will use the one that is defined near the end of the object. For your instance it will reduce to

```js
{
      name: { 
        first: 'Bob',
        last: 'Smith'
      },
      address: {
        streetName: '123 fake st',
        city: 'Baltimore'
      }

}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in the Spread in object literals section

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that. What i'm confused about is that in a lot of places it says how you must return a new object and every level of nesting must be copied. E.g here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns  " The key to updating nested data is that every level of nesting must be copied and updated appropriately " . But with the above approach, the name object is not being spread so in your new state the name object will be a reference to the old states name object and I'm trying to understand wether that's right or not and why.

Comment: You actullay correct. I missed this as well when I looked at you question. In your case have it be completely immutable you need to do spread the name object

Comment: Right so is there any pros and cons to not entirely spreading the old state and having it reference an old state object vs a completely new object for the old state?

Comment: The pros of not entirely spreading is that for some deeply nested object, you don't create a "messy" code where you spread everywhere. The cons is that if you make a mistake and accidentally a field it may cause bug in the app. It's recommended that for big, complex store you use library like Immutable.js to avoid overwriting the state

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of immutability is correct here. With the object above, you will need to spread values as you have done.

As you develop more in redux, and scale up the size of your applications, the design of your redux store will become more important. Creating several reducers and then stitching these together with `combineReducers` will help reduce complexity.

Here is an example of how you would do it for your case above. Note this is overkill for your use case. I would only split the reducers up if the state gets much more complex:

```js
const nameReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'UPDATE_FIRST_NAME') {
    return {
      ...state,
      first: action.value
    }
  } else if (action.type === 'UPDATE_LAST_NAME'){
    return {
      ...state,
      last: action.value
    }
  }
  return state
}

const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'UPDATE_CITY') {
    return {
      ...state,
      city: action.value
    }
  }
  return state
}


export default combineReducers({
  name: nameReducer,
  counter: addressReducer
})
```

Once you get to grips with redux checkout Redux Tookit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/basic-tutorial. It helps get rid of some of the boilerplate.

EDIT:

For you example above you will need to spread `name` also to be fully immutable. Consider these examples:

Not immutable

```js
const person = {
  name: {
    first: 'Bob',
    last: 'Smith'
  },
  address: {
    streetName: '123 fake st',
    city: "New York"
  }
};

const copy = {
  ...person,
  address: {
    ...person.address,
    streetName: 'myHouse'
  }
}

copy.name.first = 'Tom';

console.log({ copy, person });

/* result:

{ copy:
   { name: { first: 'Tom', last: 'Smith' },
     address: { streetName: 'myHouse', city: 'New York' } },
  person:
   { name: { first: 'Tom', last: 'Smith' },
     address: { streetName: '123 fake st', city: 'New York' } } }


*/
```

Immutable - changing the copy does not affect the `person` object.

```js
const person = {
  name: {
    first: 'Bob',
    last: 'Smith'
  },
  address: {
    streetName: '123 fake st',
    city: "New York"
  }
};

const copy = {
  name: {
    ...person.name
  },
  address: {
    ...person.address,
    streetName: 'myHouse'
  }
}

copy.name.first = 'Tom';

console.log({ copy, person });

/* result

{ copy:
   { name: { first: 'Tom', last: 'Smith' },
     address: { streetName: 'myHouse', city: 'New York' } },
  person:
   { name: { first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith' },
     address: { streetName: '123 fake st', city: 'New York' } } }

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is more a theoretical question so I understand that there would be better ways to split up the reducer there, I just had it that way to illustrate the question I was trying to ask. So in the example I had, is there any difference in functionality or performance or resistance to bugs or anything to fully spreading the old state and making it an entirely new object as well or no? If this were using an immutability library would that be returning an entirely new object or would the old state still be just a reference to the old one like it is there.

Comment: Redux relies on immutability, as does React state so its best to always insure immutability otherwise you can get unexpected behavior. If you use immutability library it will make a copy under the hood, but removes a lot of the messy spreads.

Comment: I updated by example. I missed something initially. Also check out the immer library for immutability: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just came across immer as well, looks pretty awesome!. One possible negative that comes to mind for if you were to return an entirely new object even for the old state, is that  any react useEffects or other hooks that have dependencies from one of the state properties  would re-run even if that old state wasn't actually changed. But if the unchanged part is just a reference, it wouldn't cause that to re run. Are there any negatives? If you are not directly mutating it like in your example, which you wouldn't be anyway, I can't really think of any downsides to that.

Comment: That depends on what you use as dependencies. I guess you are using `useSelector` to get the store. If you retrieve an object A from the store then every time you dispatch something to A, even when A doesn't change anything it still trigger re-render

Comment: If you mutate the underlying object and do not make a copy of it you will run into strange behavior. I can't think of a specific example. Sometimes you won't have issues but every once in a while it will cause a tricky bug. If you have different components relying on the same state, and you mutate an object directly, you can break some underlying mechanisms in redux.

Comment: The `connnect` function does some checks to prevent re-renders. One tip is to flatten your props object in the mapStateToProps. Don't pass in the entire state to your underlying component, only pass in the properies it needs. For instance your `name` component would only get `first` and `last`.

Here's a good article to read on this: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/